# open CouchDB session with admin server credential

Tags: couchdb

I have create an admin server. If I try to access to `http://localhost:5984/_utils/config.html`

futon ask me the credential for administrator, and if I digit username e password all work perfectly.
But if I try to run the command:

```
curl -X POST http://username:password@localhost:5984/_session
```

couchdb response with a HTTP 401 error. The message is

```
{error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}
```

but I'm sure that the username and the password are correct.
In effect if I try to run the command:

```
curl -X GET "http://username:password@localhost:5984/_session"
```

the response is ok and the content message tell me that I have the role of _admin.

Why therefore the POST method not working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `POST` the username and password as a URL encoded `POST` body, or as a JSON object:

```
name=root&password=relax
```

or:

```
{
    "name": "root",
    "password": "relax"
}
```

And you need to set the correct Content-Type header for either.

See the official docs http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html for details

Comment: ok thanks! with the command curl -X POST http://username:password@localhost:5984/_session -d "name=username&password=password" I can log in.
Instead I can't log in with the command curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_session -d "name=username&password=password" why?